# <marquee> receiving data from external js file

Tags: javascript, html

So i have an html document with a  running some sample pic.
However I want this data to come from a javascript file? Is this possible?

This is what i have so far:

HTML

```
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FrontEnd.css"/>
       <title> Test script for ticker </title>
     </head>
      <div class="container">
     <body>
     <div id="allTop">
        <h1>            

        </h1>
       <div class="clearfix">

        <div class="forecast">
           <div id="pic"></div>
           <div id="forecast"></div>
           <div id="temp"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
       <div id="ticker">

        <marquee>
       <img 

          src="http://www.quackit.com/pix/milford_sound/milford_sound_t.jpg"      
          Width=80 Height=80 alt="Milford Sound in New Zealand" />NewZealand   
          </marquee>

        </div>
         </div>
         <div class="captured">
        <div class="graph"></div>
         </div>   
         </body>
         </div>
       </html>
```

js function

```
            function buildList(){
            var data= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
            var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName('marquee');

            for(var i = 0; i <= data.length-1;i++){
            var newListItem = data[i] + 'there should be an img coming in  from an array here';
            listitems.innerHTML = newListItem;

            }
        }
```

So I am confused on how can i append data into marquee tags from this function?

Answer (score 2):

Simple append Data not over write

```
function buildList(){
  var data= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
  var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName('marquee');

  for(var i = 0; i <= data.length-1;i++){
    var newListItem = data[i]; //'<img something /. etc etc
    listitems[0].innerHTML += newListItem;

  }
}
```

Comment: Oh and one more thing I can see you are getting data from `document.getElementsByTagName` which will return an array since you just have one marquee use `listitems[0]`

Comment: Hey it brilliantly. Thank for the help!

Comment: Accept an answer please .. Thanks